# VSCode debugging (F5) react app gives SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

Using F5 on VSCode for react app created by create-react-app doesn't properly debug the app. "npm start" on terminal runs just fine.

It seems like 'import' works but for some reason it has an issue with "React".  It seems like VSCode didn't generate any configurations so I'm wondering if that's an issue.

This is the error I get;

```
c:\my-app\src\index.js:1
import React from 'react';
       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
Waiting for tSyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
he debugger to disconnect...
```

Comment: Gave you a +vote, as some unkind person voted you down for asking a legitimate question. Which helped me btw, so thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
import { React } from 'react';
```

instead of

```
import React from 'react';
```